# Run a script every x seconds without waiting for it to complete

Tags: shell, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a script from shell every x seconds without waiting for it to finish. For example, let's say I want to execute a python script every 5 seconds:

```
while true; do python myscript.py; sleep 5; done
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not actually start a script every 5 seconds. What it does is it waits until myscript.py is done doing whatever it was doing and then sleeps for 5 seconds and only then starts myscript.py again. I tried`watch -n5 python myscript.py` as well, which gives the same behavior. Help appreciated.

Comment: You need to run you script in the background. Try `python myscript.py &` A better way to accomplish this is with crontab - you can ask cron to run any script every N seconds.

Comment: @linuxfan cron allows to run a script every minute but not more frequent than that.

Comment: Rather than running a Python script every five seconds, it may be better to have the Python script manage itself and run continuously.  Can you tell us a bit about what the Python script does?

Comment: @JohnZwinck what the python script does is irrelevant. The idea is to launch a script, not necessarily python, ever n seconds. My python script takes 2 mins to complete. However, I want to start it every 10 seconds. So the script starts and in ten seconds it starts again as a new process.

Comment: and what is your intention for when you have 50+ incomplete processes competing with each other for system resources (RAM, disk, CPU)? Good luck.

Comment: @shelter that won't be the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
while true
do
  python myscript.py &
  sleep 5
done
```